# Compiler or runtime Install4J properties/variables

Tags: windows, macos, maven, command-line, install4j

As part of the evaluation, placing this query here as well, in case someone else has also spotted the issue and solved it.

My question is how do I pass parameters to the `install4jc` compiler from command-line when running a `maven` build, for e.g. I have something like this at the moment:

```
mvn clean package -Dinstall4j.home=$INSTALL4J_HOME -Dinstall4j.compiler=$INSTALL4J_COMPILER -Dxxxx.install4j.project.file=$XXXXX_INSTALL4J_PROJECT_FILE
```

but I get thrown this error:

```
[INFO] Loading config file
/path/to/installer-file
[INFO] install4j: compilation failed. Reason:
null------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]
[INFO] The private key is encrypted. To avoid manual intervention, set
the
[INFO] "--mac-keystore-password" command line option or the
[INFO]
"macKeystorePassword" ant task attribute.
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
Enter the password for the macOS key store:
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
BUILD FAILURE
```

I'm more concerned about passing the passwords via maven, I know how to pass them via `install4jc` command-line using the `-D` option.

Is there a `compiler.` or `runtime.` property (see https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/general/variables.html) that can be passed this password. Same applies for the `windows keystore password` as well.

Comment: I guess you're using the maven plugin from [sonatype](http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), do you? There you can predefine properties for the maven plugin in the configuration part and overwrite properties via commandline for development or security purpose with `-Dinstall4j.winKeystorePassword=xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven-Profiles for this Task.

Assuming that you want to use the Property "Hokus.Pokus" you can define a Profile in your

```
~/.m2/settings.xml
```

as follows:

```
    <profile>
        <id>MagicSecret</id>
        <properties>
            <Hokus.Pokus>Secret</Hokus.Pokus>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

You need to place this Section under the Sections

```
 <profiles>
```

Now you need to active this Profile when you run your Project like

```
mvn -PMagicSecret clean validate compile package ...
```

This Way you are able to use the Property everywhere in your pom.xml Project.